# $H_n(Z \otimes C) = (Z \otimes C)_n$

Tags: homological-algebra

(This is based on Heller's simple proof, according to Rotman)

$A, B$ are a complex and its subcomplex of boundaries. Assume all the modules in $A, B$ are flat.

We have an exact sequence of complexes:
$0\to Z \to A \to B[-1] \to 0$ and after tensoring $C$ where $C$ is any complex.
$0\to Z\otimes C \to A\otimes C \to B[-1] \otimes C \to 0$.

The corresponding long exact sequence is:

$H_{n+1}(B[-1]\otimes C) \to H_n(Z\otimes C) \to H_n(A\otimes C)\to H_{n}(B[-1]\otimes C) \to ...$

Then $H_{n+1}(B[-1]\otimes C) = (B \otimes C)_n$ and $H_n(Z \otimes C) = (Z \otimes C)_n$ since $Z, B[-1]$ have zero differentials. Thus, we may rewrite the long exact sequence as:

$(B \otimes C)_n \to (Z \otimes C)_n \to H_n(A\otimes C)\to (B \otimes C)_{n-1} \to ...$

I got a bit confused. I think as a total complex, the differential of $Z \otimes C$ should be of the form $a_{p}\otimes b_{q} \mapsto \Delta'a_{p}\otimes b_{q} + (-1)^p a_{p}\otimes \Delta''_{q}b_{q}$. So $\Delta'=0$ but we still have $\Delta''$ here, so it should not be a zero-map...

Any help would be appreicated!

Comment: Could you tell us which source you are using for this notation/terminology? I am not sure what a "cycle subcomplex" of $A$ is supposed to be: do you mean that you are taking $Z_n$ to be the kernel of $A_n \to A_{n-1}$, and then viewing $Z_{\bullet}$ as a complex with zero differential?

Comment: Yes! It is from page 679 of Rotman's introduction to homological algebra. Thx!

Comment: Something doesn't look right here: if I start with A already having zero differential, so that A=Z, then the claim you mention seems to assert that the homology of the total complex $A\otimes C$ doesn't depend on the differential of $C$. Since I don't have a copy of Rotman's book at hand, could you add some of the surrounding context? Is this something to do with a K\"unneth formula?

Comment: yes! it is the proof of his theorem! I will add all from the beginning up to this point! There's not much! Thx again!

Comment: Just to let you know it is 4am here so I am unlikely to respond for some time ...

Comment: OK. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Since $Z$ has $0$ differential, the differential of $Z\otimes C$ is $(-1)^a_Z\otimes \Delta_C$, and since everything is flat, you should get $H(Z\otimes C)\cong Z\otimes H(C)$.  I cannot figure out what else might be going on.

Comment: Crossposted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794621/h-nz-otimes-c-z-otimes-c-n)